# I stopped the BCS service on a couple of servers, but I still get connectivity errors

Tags: bcs

Stopping the service on some of the servers seems to have no effect when the system is trying to make a web service call.  Here is the error in the ULS:

The BDC Service application Business Data Connectivity Service is not accessible. The full exception text is: Could not connect to http://**********:32843/e29cc12c08754fe19f22e8260ceb23c3/BdcService.svc/http. TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 10.10.206.37:32843.

This particular server is only for external access, so the port can not be opened.  I would think that by just stopping the BCS service on it, then system would not try to call it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check, If still Orphan End point in the IIS.
After Disabling / stopping on the server, please login on the server & in the IIS see, if their any point in the Web Services still regarding the BCS. this will be a long guid..
Alos try to reset IIS On that box as well.